# Laravel 8 Seeders: Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-seeding, laravel-factory

I want to run seeders for tables `users`, `courses` and `episodes.

Here is `UserFactory`:

```
public function definition()
    {
        static $password;
        return [
            'name' => $this->faker->name,
            'email' => $this->faker->unique()->safeEmail,
            'password' => $password ?: $password = bcrypt('secret'),
            'remember_token' => Str::random(10),
        ];
    }
```

And here is `EpisodeFactory`:

```
public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'title' => $this->faker->sentence(),
            'body' => $this->faker->paragraph(5),
            'videoUrl' => 'https://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4',
        ];
    }
```

And this is `CourseFactory`:

```
public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'title' => $this->faker->sentence(),
            'body' => $this->faker->paragraph(5),
            'price' => $this->faker->numberBetween(1000,10000),
            'image' => $this->faker->imageUrl(),
        ];
    }
```

Then I added this to the `DatabaseSeeder`:

```
public function run()
    {
        $user = \App\Models\User::factory()->count(30)->create();
        \App\Models\Course::factory()->count(5)->create(['user_id' => $user->id ])->each(function ($course) {
            \App\Models\Episode::factory()->count( rand(6 , 20))->make()->each(function ($episode , $key) use ($course){
                $episode->number = $key +1;
                $course->episodes()->save($episode);
            });
        });
    }
```

Now when I run `php artisan db:seed`, I get this error:

> Exception  **Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.**

Which is referring to `create(['user_id' => $user->id ])` at `DatabaseSeeder`.

So what's going wrong here? How can I solve this issue?

And here is also the Migration of `users` table:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Also if you need any other Migration or Model codes to look at, just let me know, I will add them immediately.

Comment: You're creating 30 users, which `id` is it supposed to magically know to use as `$user->id`?

Comment: @BrianThompson I don't understand.  What should I do to solve this?

Comment: `$user = \App\Models\User::factory()->count(30)->create()` creates 30 users correct? The `count(30)` instructs it to. That means `$user` **does not** contain 1 user like the name implies, it holds a collection of all 30 users. So `$user->id` doesn't make sense, because there's 30 ids. You would have to choose one of the ids somehow. I can't say how because I don't know what you're trying to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

the problem could be in the import of the models. import the user model and do something like

```
$user = User::all();
```

above the factory you have to initialize the variable